# Write stack trace to Extent Reports from the @afterMethod in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

In the @afterMethod of TestNG, I am wanting to capture the stack trace and include that in Extent Reports, however, I'm not able to find a good solution. I realize there are tons of threads on printing the stack trace, but none of them are giving me what I want. I am wanting the method and line number that caused the failure. I do not care if the stack trace is huge, as I want to be able to see what lead up to the failing line.

Here is an example of where I write to Extent Reports:

```
    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult result, Method method) throws InterruptedException {

        ExtentTest test = ExtentTestManager.getTest();

        // Get thread id
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();

        if (result.getStatus() != ITestResult.SKIP)
        {

            String os = StoredVariables.getos().get();

            String resultStatus = "";
            // Write passing tests to Extent Reports
            if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
                    test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "<span class='label success'>" + result.getName() + "</span>");
                    resultStatus = "Passed";
                    StoredVariables.getfailedTest().set(false);
                } 

            // Write failing tests to Extent Reports
            if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
                test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "<span class='label failure'>" + result.getName() + "</span>", "<pre>Results = " + result.getThrowable().getCause() + "\n\n" + result.getThrowable().getMessage() + "</pre>");
                resultStatus = "Failed";
                StoredVariables.getfailedTest().set(true);
            } 

            System.out.println("TEST RESULT: " + method.getName() + " - Thread " + id + " = " + resultStatus);
```

`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` just gives me "[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@2e1ef60"

Printing out the `ItestResult result` directly gets me closer by providing the following, but there are no line numbers:

> [TestResult name=functionChecks status=FAILURE
>   method=ExampleScripts.functionChecks()[pri:0,
>   instance:_exampleScripts.ExampleScripts@731a74c] output=Completed
>   executing following method : ExampleScripts.functionChecks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

idk if this helps but this worked for me ... this is from my TestListener base class:

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult){ 
 ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.FAIL,iTestResult.getThrowable().toString());
}
```

Comment: This is in a roundabout way what I am doing. The .toString() is what I was missing. Here is how I am handling it now: // Set the stacktrace to a String
   StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
         result.getThrowable().printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw)); 
         String stacktrace = sw.toString();
      // Write the stack trace to extent reports
         test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "<span class='label failure'>" + result.getName() + "</span>", "<pre>Stacktrace:\n" + stacktrace + "</pre>");

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass throwable to the log and the exception will be printed correctly.

Reference:  http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#logging-exceptions

```
test.fail(result.getThrowable());
```

The solution is also available in TeatNG examples section of the docs.

Comment: using result.getThrowable()) only gives me this:     "java.lang.AssertionError: Failed expected [true] but found [false]". Still no line numbers and I am trying to capture the source of the failure, not necessarily the last method call

Comment: @DustinN. Hei. I'm using the same result.getThrowable() and I'm getting a full stacktrace in the ExtentReports log. What extentreport version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Extent Reports version 2.41.0 and Selenium 2.53.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import com.google.common.base.Throwables;

//and in after method:
Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(result.getThrowable()));
```

Full method:

```
@AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {

        System.out.println("Status is :" + result.getStatus());
        if (result.getStatus() == 1) {
            System.out.println("Passed");
            test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test Passed", test.addBase64ScreenShot(CaptureScreenShot.capture()));
        } else {

            test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Failed", test.addBase64ScreenShot(CaptureScreenShot.capture())+Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(result.getThrowable()));
        }

        driver.quit();

    }
```

ItestResult has the method 'getThrowable' that gives the throwable that caused the issue. You can print it by converting to string using Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(throwable)

You can also use result.getThrowable.getStackTrace() to get a stack array from which you have to print each element to see the full array. eg: result.getThrowable.getStackTrace()[0] prints first line.